COLAB：Questions regarding the display or settlement of colab computing units
I purchased 100 computing units and the colab pro package on the 11th and 19th of this month respectively.
So I have 200 compute units here.
And I have always used T4GPU.
On the afternoon of May 21,When I close colab, disconnect the link and delete the runtime, it shows that there are still about 140 computing units.
But on the evening of May 21, when I opened colab again, it showed that there were only 39 computing units left.
There are 100 computational units missing.
I made sure that I disconnected the link and deleted the runtime after using colab. Moreover, even if I forget to do this, when t4gpu deducts 1.84 computing units per hour, it will not be deducted from 140 computing units to the remaining 39 computing units in about 6 hours.
I don't know if this is a display error or a system calculation error, but as of now, this problem has not been resolved...
I try this:
I submitted questions on github and stackoverflow respectively, and sent feedback emails to the feedback email address provided by colab.
